# What prevents get-member to display events?

Tags: events, properties, powershell-3.0, member

I can't use get-member to display an object event whereas getevents() method works. 
Why ?

```
PS>([System.Timers.Timer] |gm -MemberType event |measure).count  
0                                                                

PS>[System.Timers.Timer].getevents().count  
2                                   

PS>[System.Timers.Timer].getevents() |select name  

Name                                               
----                                               
Elapsed                                            
Disposed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I've seen my error

```
$t=New-Object -TypeName system.timers.timer 
PS>$t |gm -MemberType event |select name   

Name                                       
----                                       
Disposed                                   
Elapsed       

PS>$t.GetType().fullname  
System.Timers.Timer      

PS>[system.timers.timer].GetType().FullName 
System.RuntimeType
```